# Using the Includes method on a string with multiple values

Tags: javascript, string

I want to check if a string has any of the following words, apple, pear, orange and if it does, do some code. However my code only currently checks for the first word, apple and not the other 2. Fruit variable gets sent from a client side.

```
var fruit = fruit;

if (fruit.includes(["apple", "pear", "orange"])
{ 
    //do some code
}
```

I tried | instead of a comma

I need it so it checks all for all of the words, not just the first

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `some` method:

```
if (["apple", "pear", "orange"].some(x => fruit.includes(x))) {
    // Do something...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex instead of `includes()` with a loop to solve it.

Demo:

```js
var fruit = "green dpear";

if (/\b(apple|pear|orange)\b/.test(fruit)) {
  console.log('match');
} else {
  console.log('not_match');
}
```

Comment: @KoshVery if so then maybe i need a `\s+` in a regex. Beside, `'spearmint'.includes('pear')` return true also.

Comment: You're getting closer =)) Try `/\b(apple|pear|orange)\b/`.

Answer (score 1):

`.includes()` returns a Boolean (true/false) and it appears that you want the actual matches to return instead. `.find()` returns the match but like `.include()` it stops after the first match so you'll need to iterate through the search keys.

The following demo runs `.filter()` through the array to be searched (`primary`). `.filter()` will return the current value that's evaluated as true. By running `.includes()` on the search array (`search`) inside the `.filter()` you can search each element of array `primary`.

```js
const primary = ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma', 'delta', 'epsilon'];
const search = ['beta', 'delta', 'omega'];

const matches = (array1, array2) => array1.filter(word => array2.includes(word));

console.log(matches(primary, search));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `forEach` loop

```
const fruit = ['apple', 'orange'];

fruit.forEach( function(v, i) {
    if ( fruit[i].includes('orange') ) {
    // do you stuff
  }
});
```